# Conditional regex replacement

Tags: python, regex

With Python, You can check if a group is empty before replacing text?

Example:

```
[user] John Marshal   -->   [user]<br><strong>Jonh Marshal<strong>

John Marshal   -->   <strong>Jonh Marshal<strong>
```

The regex should use this is, but with the "condition" to insert the < br> only if group 1 is found.

```
title = re.sub(r'^\s*(\[.*?\])?\s*(.*)', r'\1<br><strong>\2</strong>', title)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Group one is *always* found because you allow empty matches.

You want to match at least one character, not 0 or more, so use `.+?`:

```
title = re.sub(r'^\s*(\[.+?\])?\s*(.*)', r'\1<br><strong>\2</strong>', title)
```

Now the match will throw an exception if group one is missing. Make use of that:

```
try:
    title = re.sub(r'^\s*(\[.+?\])?\s*(.*)', r'\1<br><strong>\2</strong>', title)
except re.error:
    title = re.sub(r'^\s*(.*)', r'<strong>\1</strong>', title)
```

The alternative is to use a function to do the replacement:

```
def title_sub(match):
    if match.group(1):
        return '{}<br><strong>{}</strong>'.format(*match.groups())
    return '<strong>{}</strong>'.format(match.group(2))

title = re.sub(r'^\s*(\[.+?\])?\s*(.*)', title_sub, title)
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^\s*(\[.+?\])?\s*(.*)', title_sub, '[user] John Marshal')
'[user]<br><strong>John Marshal</strong>'
>>> re.sub(r'^\s*(\[.+?\])?\s*(.*)', title_sub, 'John Marshal')
'<strong>John Marshal</strong>'
```

Comment: Thanks! I use the try, solve my problem. I wondered it would be possible with pure regex.

Comment: You cannot do conditional substitutions, no.

Comment: If I use a function I cannot use group name in the replace regex, can I?

Comment: @Lerner: sure you can. The match object passed in gives you access to all groups, including named groups.

Comment: Say if I have `return '<strong>{}</strong>\g<a_group_name_in_pattern>'` I will just get the result with `\g<a_group_name_in_pattern>` containing in it. I can only do it by assigning `match.group("a_group_name_in_pattern")` to a variable(say varible4group) and `return  '<strong>{}</strong>'+variable4group`

Comment: @Lerner: You can use `'<strong>{variable4group}</strong>'.format(**match.groupdict())`.

Answer (score 0):

To do conditional substitutions with regex in Python I've came up with the following solution:

```
@classmethod
def normalize_query_string(cls, query_string):

    def replace_fields(match):
        x = match.group("field")
        if x == "$certHash":
            return "ci.C.H:"
        return "{}:".format(x)

    result = re.sub(r"(?P<field>\$[\w.]+):", replace_fields, query_string)
    return result
```