# regex: conditional substitute with group name in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

The string1: "4-5%" and string2: "5%"
The expected output: "percent 4 to percent 5", "percent 5" respectively.

My regex:

```
percent = 
    {
        "pattern": "(?P<range>(?P<from>[\d.]+)(%)?[?\-～ ~〜~—])?(?P<to>[\d.]+)%",
        "repl": r"(?(range)percent \g<from>to )percent\g<to>)",
        "string": thestring
    }

print re.sub(**percent)
```

What I get for the first(`percent["string"]="4-5%"`) is `(?(range)percent 5 to)percent 7)`, and it doesn't work for the second(when string="5%")

I know the value of the repl cannot contain conditions but (how) can I implement what I want? Can I only use two regexes in this context?

Comment: 3 regex will do? Check my answer.

Comment: I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17476793/3552975

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional regex replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476775/conditional-regex-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import re

a="""
4-5%
hello world 4-5% hello world
5%
"""
print re.sub(r'(\d)%', r'\1', re.sub(r'-',r' to ',re.sub(r'(\d(?=(-\d)?%))',r'percent \1',a)))
```

Output:

```
percent 4 to percent 5
hello world percent 4 to percent 5 hello world
percent 5
```